# Passing member function as parameter

Tags: c++

So I have this function:

```
void EventDispatcher::Subscribe(string eventName, void (*callback)(void *))
{
....
}
```

I am trying to pass class member function as a callback parameter there.

```
typedef void (*method)(void*);

void EventTester::RunTests()
{
    _dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

    Event eventOne("one");

    _dispatcher->Register("one", eventOne);

    method p = &onOne;

    _dispatcher->Subscribe("one", p);
}

void EventTester::onOne(void *args)
{
    std::cout<<"Event one\n";
}
```

obviously this doesn't compile because onOne is not static and a member function. Is there any way of making it work this way?

Comment: For these C-style callbacks, in additional to the C-style function to call you generally can also provide `void*` user data the function will be called with. So you'd call `Subscribe("blah", my_member_function_callback, this);`. But if you're in control of this interface, just use `std::function<>`.

Comment: If you can't change the signature of EventDispatcher::Subscribe(), then there is still a way to do this through a wrapper, but this requires that the `void*` argument in the callback is passed by you, and I don't see a way to do that in the code you posted. The idea is to pass an `EventTester` instance in the `void*` argument on which to call onOne().

Comment: @GManNickG: That might not work as [member function pointer might be larger](http://lazarenko.me/2013/04/28/cc-pointers-to-member-functions/) than `sizeof(void*)`. Plus, adjustment to `this` might be required (can be done with static cast before converting to void, though?)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I'm suggesting creating a non-member function that accepts the `void*`, casts it to the class type, and calls the member function; not passing the member function directly anywhere. And yes, in practice you should adjust `this` to a consistent type for the callback to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use boost in C++03 or `std::bind` and `std::function` in C++11:

```
typedef boost::function<void(void*)> func_type;

void EventDispatcher::Subscribe(const string& eventName, const func_type& func_)
{
  if ( ! func_.empty() ) {
    // you could call the function
    func_(NULL);
  }
}


//Register looks like in a member function of EventTester:
...
_dispatcher->Subscribe("one",boost::bind(&EventTester::onOne,this,_1));
...
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean C++03 instead of C++01?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going off the assumption that you have the ability to modify the signature of `Subscribe`. If not, my answer may not apply.

As you already noted, your pointer-to-member (aka `method`) is not the same as a plain function pointer. To use a pointer-to-member, you have to supply the class instance to call the function on as part of the method execution.

You could modify `Subscribe` to explicitly take in a pointer-to-member, which would expect an additional argument (the `class` instance). You would need `Subscribe` to store both the function pointer, and a pointer to your object instance. This would then require that all callbacks be implemented as pointers-to-members.

The preferred way to solve this problem is to use `bind` (either `std::bind` or `boost::bind`).

You would need to change your `Subscribe` function to take in a `std/boost::function` object instead of an explicit function pointer. This would permit callers of the Subscribe method to pass in any `callable` object (See the examples in the documentation of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function))

You can then use `bind` to connect your class instance to your method pointer. This will return a functor object which will do the work of holding both your pointer-to-member and a pointer to your class instance.

For an example of how to use bind, [see this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)